# Error on running CouchRest.put()

Tags: ruby, couchdb

I need to update a couchdb document, when i try and run the command in irb

```
  CouchRest.put('http://localhost:5984/db', {"_id": "1","_rev": "sdf", "test": "testing"})
```

I get an error -

RestClient::Request::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: {"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}

While in the same console, I am able to successfully run -

```
  CouchRest.post('http://localhost:5984/db', {"test": "testing"})
```

Could somebody help with this please.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is straightforward.  The API states that a PUT against the name of a db (in your example, "db") attempts to create a new database, which requires admin privileges.

To create a new document, you may use a POST as you did successfully, but the API documents discourage the use of POSTs.  PUTs can be used for both creates and updates.

To update an existing document, use a PUT with the ID of the document in the path of the URL and the desired revision to update in the JSON; e.g., `CouchRest.put('http://localhost:5984/db/1', {"rev": "sdf", "test": "testing"})`

For more information, see the API documentation at [Apache's Document API doc in the Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API).